# ring of integers of a cyclotomic extension of $\mathbb{Q}_p$

Tags: nt.number-theory, algebraic-number-theory

Let $p$ be a prime and $\xi_n$ a nth primitive root of unity. What is the ring of integers of $\mathbb{Q}_p(\xi_n)$? Is it $\mathbb{Z}_p[\xi_n]$?

Comment: You may find this useful https://mathoverflow.net/questions/12463/adding-an-n-th-root-to-q-p

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. This follows e.g. from Propositions 16 and 17 in Section IV.4 of Serre: Local fields.

Indeed, let $n=p^mn'$, where $(n',p)=1$. By Proposition 17, $\mathbb{Q}_p(\zeta_{p^m})$ has ring of integers $\mathbb{Z}_p[\zeta_{p^m}]$. Then, applying Proposition 16 to the local field $\mathbb{Q}_p(\zeta_{p^m})$, we see that $\mathbb{Q}_p(\zeta_{p^m},\zeta_{n'})$ has ring of integers $\mathbb{Z}_p[\zeta_{p^m},\zeta_{n'}]$. However, it is straightforward that $\mathbb{Q}_p(\zeta_{p^m},\zeta_{n'})=\mathbb{Q}_p(\zeta_{n})$ and $\mathbb{Z}_p[\zeta_{p^m},\zeta_{n'}]=\mathbb{Z}_p[\zeta_{n}]$, hence $\mathbb{Q}_p(\zeta_{n})$ has ring of integers $\mathbb{Z}_p[\zeta_{n}]$.